# How can I pass the userID from PHP to Android(Shared Preferences)

Tags: php, android, sql

I am making an app that shares the same database as my website. I maintain the login session throughout the activities and I can get the username, but how can I get the User ID(PK) from the user who is logging in? I've got all the tables well created and I can communicate with the database with the app and the website. Please help me

//PHP FILE

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Getting values 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    //Creating sql query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilizadores WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";

    //importing dbConnect.php script 
    require_once('connection.php');

    //executing query
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    //fetching result
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //if we got some result 
    if(isset($check)){

        //displaying success 
        echo "success";
    }else{
        //displaying failure
        echo "failure";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

//Android File

```
public class Config {

    //URL to our login.php file
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.43/Teste/login.php";

    //Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id_utilizador";


    //If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
    public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

    //Keys for Sharedpreferences
    //This would be the name of our shared preferences
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";

    //This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
    public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

    //This would be used to store the id of current logged in user
    public static final String ID_SHARED_PREF = "id_utilizador";

    //We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to retrieve a server-side variable (the userID).
You can make your server to output that variable if login was successful, then parse the server response from your Android app.

Comment: If you ask this question, you should learn first how client-server communication works. Then learn PHP (is an easy language to learn and to make things), so finally you can deduce that you should print your userId variable, instead of printing "success" in your PHP code.

Comment: I define my userID variable as a SESSION variable in php our not?

Comment: Then you have to print $_SESSION["your variable name here"].

Comment: Like this?
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  //Getting values 
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  
  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Utilizadores WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
  
  require_once('connection.php');
  
  $sql = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  
 
  $check = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_BOTH);
  
  //if we got some result 
  if(isset($check)){
   
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['id_utilizador'] = $check['id_utilizador'];
   echo "id_utilizador";
  }else{
   //displaying failure
   echo "failure";
  }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885110/json-exception-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject-appears here I have my full program in order to give you context. If you please help me :/